# Complex Analysis - Showing function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I have the following problem:

> Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in a region $U^+$. Define $U^{-}: = \{ z: \overline{z} \in U^+\}$. Prove that $g: U^{-} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ given by the formula $g(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic and give $g'$ in terms of $f$.

I don't really know how to start this problem.

I have tried writing out the limit definition for $f$ and then the limit definition for $g$, but getting from $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ to $f(z)$ doesn't seem easy.

Some help or tips would be appreciated.

Aside: Does anyone know any good sources of problems like this (ideally with solutions)? I have an exam on complex analysis tomorrow so could do with the practice.

Comment: You can try to find a candidate with Cauchy Riemann equations. Then you show this candidate is the derivative.

Comment: I don't know a source to find many such questions, but my advice would be to either go to the library or look online for complex analysis books and look through the exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can prove this.  For example, you can use Cauchy-Riemann equations plus continuity of derivatives, or you can use limit definition, or you can use more advanced tools such as Morera's theorem.

For example, with the limit definition,
$$
\frac{g(z)-g(w)}{z-w}=\frac{\overline{f(\bar{z})}-\overline{f(\bar{w})}}{\overline{\bar{z}-\bar{w}}}=\overline{\left(\frac{f(\bar{z})-f(\bar{w})}{\bar{z}-\bar{w}}\right)}
$$
which tends to $\overline{f'(\bar{z})}$ as $w\to z$ in $U^-$ (equivalently $\bar{w}\to\bar{z}$ in $U^+$).

Comment: Oh that is neat, I didn't think to do that with the modulus... How would you use Morera's theorem? Isn't it difficult to show that for _every_ closed curve you have a vanishing integral?

Comment: $\int_C g(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_{\bar{C}}\overline{f(\zeta)\,\mathrm{d}\zeta}=0$ for all closed curve $C$ in $U^-$, by Cauchy.  So Morera gives $g$ holomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $f(x+iy) = u_1(x,y)+i v_1(x,y)$ and $g(x+iy) = u_2(x,y) + i v_2(x,y)$, using $g(z) = \overline{f(\overline z)}$ express $u_2$ and $v_2$ in terms of $u_1$ and $v_1$. Now check the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Ok, so I've shown the C-R equations hold. But then how do I find $g'$ in terms of $f$?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove, $g'(z) = \partial_x u_2(x,y) + \partial_x v_2(x,y)$, so use $u_1$ and $v_1$ again to write it in terms of derivative of $f$.